# Use Gradle API to resolve dependency into Gradle cache

Tags: gradle

I'm building an adapter for multiple versions of a library.
In my unit tests I want to test against all those versions. They are available on central and I can resolve them like so:

```
def version = '2.0'
def project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
def config = project.configurations.create('config');
def dependency = project.dependencies.create("org.company:artifact:${version}")
config.dependencies.add(dependency)
project.repositories {
    jcenter()
}
configuration.resolve()
```

The problem is that the dependencies are downloaded to the temporary project dir in a `userHome` directory. The `ProjectBuilder` doesn't provide a way to set a specific path as `userHome`. So the same dependency must be downloaded again and again. Does the Gradle API provide a way to dynamically resolve dependencies from and into `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1` or wherever a normal buildscript would resolve dependencies from/into?

Comment: You haven’t mentioned [`org.gradle.testfixtures.ProjectBuilder.withGradleUserHomeDir(java.io.File)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/testfixtures/ProjectBuilder.html#withGradleUserHomeDir(java.io.File)) in your question. Have you tried that already?

Answer (score 0):

Using `TemporaryFolder`, you can set the `ProjectBuilder` directory:

```
@Rule
public static TemporaryFolder projectFolder
@BeforeClass
public static void setupOnce() {
    projectFolder = new TemporaryFolder()
}
```

Then:

```
Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder()
  .withProjectDir(projectFolder.getRoot())
  .withName("project name")
  .build()
```